# Swype Private Beta for HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire, swype

I read [here](http://androidforums.com/htc-desire/63433-swype.html#post564831) that you can email the Swype developers to ask for an invite for the private beta of Swype on the HTC Desire, and you may or may not get an invite. I'd like to try it out as it looks pretty neat.

- Is the private beta still running?
- Is there some official announcement that describes how to register for the private beta?
- What email should I write to and what should I write to increase my chances of an invite?

Comment: what does "for HTC Desire" and the tag "htc-desire" have to do with the swype beta? it's hardware agnostic: "The beta is open to all phones using Android which DO NOT already have Swype pre-installed by the phone manufacturer / carrier." per http://beta.swype.com/android/agreement/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your questions:

- The beta is still running
- http://beta.swype.com/
- The beta is currently closed

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the "Register" link and see what happens. If nothing else, hopefully I'll at least get a mail as soon as the product goes on the market.

Comment: @Mark I got in on it the very first go they had a beta.  I think they've only opened it up once since then.  The only other way to get it is to either purchase a phone that has it.  I've been hearing good things about UltraKeyboard as an alternative, haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I just got an email from SwypeInc saying that they have activated my Beta account. :-)

Comment: Beta must have reopened, because I set up an account and got the installer last week.

Answer (score 2):

There are apk's out there.  I use it on my Desire and it is a great keyboard alternative.

Comment: Is that legal to do that?